# Как сделать кнопку еще раз в aiogram?

Tags: aiogram, бот

Есть такой код, хочу сделать кнопку сыграть еще раз, чтобы можно было играть по кругу, помогите пожалуйста

```
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN, parse_mode="HTML")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def on_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Здарова, {message.from_user.username}! \nЧтобы начать игру напиши /play")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["play"])
async def play(message:types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Начнем")
    await sleep (1)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Очередь бота")
    bot_data = await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    bot_data = bot_data["dice"]["value"]
    await sleep (5)

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Твоя очередь")
    user_data = await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    user_data = user_data["dice"]["value"]
    await sleep (5)

if bot_data > user_data:
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты проиграла")
    print("ИИ выйграл")
elif bot_data < user_data:
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты победила")
    print("ИИ не оправдал надежд")
else:
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Пусть Бог вас рассудит",)
    print("ничья")
await sleep (1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, для этого у Telegram есть [KeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton), а у aiogram [встроенные фильтры](https://telegra.ph/Vstroennye-filtry-v-aiogram-12-30).

Если их использовать, то выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(filters.Text(contains="Новая игра", ignore_case=True))
@dp.message_handler(commands=["play"])
async def cmd_play(message: types.Message):
    reply_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=False, selective=False
    ).add(types.KeyboardButton(text="Новая игра"))

    await message.reply("play!", reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Во-вторых, Ваше определение результата находится вне функции play(), странно, что это вообще работает. Ну а если исправить это и использовать пример выше для начала новой игры, то получится так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=["play"])
async def play(message:types.Message):
    reply_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=False, selective=False
    ).add(types.KeyboardButton(text="Новая игра"))
    
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Начнем")
    await sleep (1)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Очередь бота")
    bot_data = await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    bot_data = bot_data["dice"]["value"]
    await sleep (5)

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Твоя очередь")
    user_data = await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    user_data = user_data["dice"]["value"]
    await sleep (5)

    if bot_data > user_data:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты проиграла", reply_markup=reply_markup)
        print("ИИ выйграл")
    elif bot_data < user_data:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты победила", reply_markup=reply_markup)
        print("ИИ не оправдал надежд")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Пусть Бог вас рассудит", reply_markup=reply_markup)
        print("ничья")
    await sleep (1)
```